# Clear input field when a key is pressed in it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried to clear the input field on the **keypress** event in angularjs directive.

Html:

```
<input class="magic-input" type="number" ng-model="demo.input">
```

Directive:

```
.directive('magicInput', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        elem.bind('keypress', function () {
            ngModel.$setViewValue('');
            ngModel.$render(); 
        });
    }
}
});
```

The problem here is that the directive clear current text but the **pressed key** remains in the input field.

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/pratikkulshreshth/ytwt83sp/) is the fiddle for this problem.

Comment: what you want exactly , can you explain your requirement for better understanding of the question.

Comment: If you press a key the directive will clean the input always so you can't type there. I don't understand what do you want to do, give us more information please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chang your link function to the following :

```
 link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    elem.bind('keypress', function (e) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue('');
        ngModel.$render(); 
        e.preventDefault();  //Note this
    });
}
```

`e.preventDefault()` will prevent the keypress event from completing.

Answer (score 3):

As i can understand your issue.I can suggest try using "**keyup**" event on place of "**keypress**" event.

try this

```
.directive('maginInput', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        elem.bind('keyup', function () {
            ngModel.$setViewValue('');
            ngModel.$render(); 
        });
    }
}
});
```

Check this fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ytwt83sp/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Viplock.
This solves my problem. It would be great if you can explain why my code wasn't working.

Comment: @Pratik Please accept answer if your problem is solved

Comment: By "keypress" event first the code with execute and clear the value from the input field and after that update the value of text box by the key value. But in "keyup" event it will fist update the value of text box by the key value(pressed key) then execute the code to clear the text box value. Hope this explanation would be clear to you.